# Trying to incorperate a really simple light box. How do I stay centered on scroll?

Tags: javascript, css, lightbox

Working on tarting up a very old site as a new site is being built elsewhere and wanting to incorperate a super simple lightbox type display but not sure how to make it work.

Here is the page as it stands:

http://www.onboardtraining.co.uk/johnboyce

When clicking on the 3 rows of cars on the right it calls a javascript function built around code from this page :

http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2007/08/22/create-a-lightbox-effect-only-with-css-no-javascript-needed/

Only thing is the dark background layer doesnt fully expand out to 100% even though it says this inside the CSS code and both the background layer and container layer dont stay fixed on screen, if the visitor has scrolled down a bit then clicked the thumbnail the layers appear further up the page and only partially cover the screen, same if the user tries to scroll.

Lastly although the demo code works ok (bar the above) in IE, FF and Chrome, on the iPhone the lightbox appears shoved over to the left.

Sorry for the massive question with many branches, just learning my way around things CSS at the moment and coming out of the dark ages :)

Thanks,

Rik

***Edit*** - I dont want to use any external jquery plug ins thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the easiest method:

```
.black_overlay {
    position: fixed;
    _position: absolute;
}
```

`position: fixed` [is supported](http://caniuse.com/css-fixed) in every browser except IE6 - support for which is no longer relevant to most websites. `_position: absolute` is applied in only IE6, and stops the page breaking in that browser.

You should leave the white box as it is (don't make it `position: fixed`), because it does not size itself intelligently to the dimensions of the window.

No idea about the iPhone part of your question.

---

Firstly, you should update your doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

That is no good, because it causes [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode). In Internet Explorer especially, many things simply do not work or are otherwise entirely broken in Quirks Mode. Update your doctype to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Comment: That is fantastic help, thank you for taking the time to point me in the right direction :) Could you possibly tell me how to have the white box scroll / appear in the centre of the page and stay there too ? Many thanks, Rik

Comment: You're welcome. You should ask a new question about that (be sure to include your `picpopper` function and also a link to your site), it's too far off the tangent of your current question. Anyway, I don't have my JavaScript hat on right now.

Answer (score 0):

Use this jquery lightbox plugin:

http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/